# Are there any algorithms for regular Egyptian fractions?

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, egyptian-fractions

Let's call an [Egyptian fraction](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EgyptianFraction.html), denoted by $E$, *$1$-regular* iff there exists some $a \in \mathbb{N}$ such that it can be expressed as folows: $$E = \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{a+1} + \frac{1}{a+2} + \frac{1}{a+3} + \dots $$
We generalize this notion of regularity by proposing that an Egyptian fraction $E$ is *$n$-regular* iff there is some $a \in \mathbb{N}$ such that:

$$E = \frac{1}{a^{n}} + \frac{1}{(a+1)^{n}} + \frac{1}{(a+2)^{n}} + \frac{1}{(a+3)^{n}} + \dots $$

**Questions**:

1. Has this concept of regularity of Egyptian fractions already been proposed elsewhere in the literature on the subject? If so, could you please point towards some sources?
2. Can all real numbers be expressed by a *$1$-regular* Egyptian fraction? The same question applies to *$n$-regular* Egyptian fractions, for $n \neq 1$.
3. Are there any algorithms that are able to convert a real number into a *$1$-regular* Egyptian fraction?
4. Are there any algorithms that are able to convert a real number into an *$n$-regular* Egyptian fraction, for $n \neq 1$? If so, for which values of $n$ has this been achieved?

Comment: It is not clear what is your definition of $1$-regularity. The sum $\frac{1}{a+1} + \frac{1}{a+2} + \cdots$ diverges for all $a \in \mathbb{N}$. For $n > 1$, no number $> \zeta(2)$ can be $n$-regular as $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(a+k)^n} \le \zeta(n) \le \zeta(2)$.

Comment: @achillehui Ah, yes. The sum diverges if there are an infinite amount of terms. So for $1$-regularity, I should restrict the definition to a finite amount of terms. I agree on your second point. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer to (2)**.

If I understand correctly, your sums depend on three parameters: $a$, $n$ and the length of the partial sum. Since these three parameters are natural numbers, there are only countably many such sums. Therefore they can not exhaust the set of positive real numbers.